# Subquery does not want to grouping

Tags: sql-server

I need to group only `dbo_ordetail.typee` but this code insist to add `orderno,dued,deld` in the grouping How I can rewrite the bellow code in SQL server 2005 with only `dbo_ordetail.typee` group.

below sql query from ms access

```
SELECT    dbo_ordetail.typee, Sum(dbo_ordetail.qty) AS SumOfqty, 
          (SELECT sum(dbo_ordetail.qty)
               FROM dbo_ordetail
               WHERE dbo_ordetail.ordern=o.orderno AND
                   datediff("d",now(), o.dued) > 30 AND
                   o.deld is NULL
          ) AS 30day
FROM      dbo_ordert o INNER JOIN dbo_ordetail ON o.orderno = dbo_ordetail.ordern
GROUP BY  dbo_ordetail.typee;
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler gets confused by the use of `dbo_orderdetail` inside both the main-query and the subquery. Try to distinguish them with different aliases:

```
SELECT 
   dbo_od.typee, 
   Sum(dbo_od.qty) AS SumOfqty, 
   (SELECT sum(dbo_od_1.qty) 
       FROM dbo_ordetail dbo_od_1
       where dbo_od_1.ordern=o.orderno 
       and datediff("d",now(), o.dued) > 30 
       AND o.deld is NULL) as 30day 
FROM dbo_ordert o 
INNER JOIN dbo_ordetail dbo_od ON o.orderno = dbo_od.ordern 
GROUP BY dbo_od.typee
```

Now you have a clear distinction between the two tables in both contexts.

Comment: I think the problem is `o.orderno` inside the subquery. Since you dont group it within the outer `group by` clause he cannot aggregate it and complains. This might change the result, but try to add `o.orderno` to the `group by` clause.

Answer (score 0):

your query formation is wrong.. It should be like below

```
        SELECT    dbo_ordetail.typee, Sum(dbo_ordetail.qty) AS SumOfqty, 30day
    from

    (SELECT o.orderno as orderno  , sum(dbo_ordetail.qty) FROM dbo_ordetail
        WHERE     dbo_ordetail.ordern=o.orderno and datediff("d",now(), o.dued) > 30 AND o.deld is NULL) AS 30day
group by o.orderno,o.dued,o.deld)
        o INNER JOIN dbo_ordetail ON o.orderno = dbo_ordetail.ordern
        GROUP BY  dbo_ordetail.typee;
```

Comment: @user3800618 Edited my post.. this should work now... If not then let me know `o.orderno` referring to which table?

Comment: again error and o.orderno is equal to  dbo_ordert.orderno

Comment: is `o` a table if yes then why didn't apply a join in sub query?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work for you:

```
SELECT typee, SUM(qty) AS SumOfqty, _30day
FROM    
    (SELECT   dbo_ordetail.typee, dbo_ordetail.qty, 
              (SELECT sum(dbo_ordetail.qty)
               FROM   dbo_ordetail
               WHERE  dbo_ordetail.ordern=o.orderno AND
                      DATEDIFF(d, GETDATE(), o.dued) > 30 AND
                      o.deld is NULL
              ) AS _30day
     FROM     dbo_ordert o INNER JOIN dbo_ordetail ON o.orderno = dbo_ordetail.ordern) t
GROUP BY  typee, _30day;
```

Columnn names cannot start with numerics in SQL Server, so I prefixed it with an underscore.